# Insert Delayed Error

Tags: mysql, insert, delay

I just received an email from my hosting provider stating the following:

Your DB has been blocked because of high MySQL usage.
This was caused by the following query:
| 17649732 | DELAYED         | localhost | k*********    | Delayed insert | 22   | Waiting for INSERT |

I've tried looking to see what these numbers and information mean, but I've been unable to find any helpful information. How do I go about resolving an error of this nature and/or how do I figure out where the error is to resolve?

Comment: Have you tried asking your hosting provider?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on my the MySQL engine is configured, the "offending" query could well be classified by the MySQL engine as a so called "slow query" and could appear in the "slow query" log.

You need to talk to whoever configured the MySQL engine that serves your site, to determine the status of the "slow query" log, so you can see if the query is shown in the log.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically due to the service provider using a script to look for offensive mysql behaviour.  In this case, that line is from the processlist.  You issued a INSERT DELAYED statement, which causes mysql to create a "Delayed Insert thread."  This thread will live until mysql has a reason to kill it.

The 22 in the line means that the thread was in the "Waiting for INSERT" state for 22 seconds.  My guess is that their script looks for queries that are taking longer than 15 or 20 seconds to run, but they only check every 10 seconds or so, leading to the number being not an even 10 or 5 seconds.

In any case, this line could never appear in the slow query log.  I would ask the provider how they determined that you were using mysql excessivly, and maybe point them to the mysql documentation for delayed inserts.

It is also possible that you actually were issuing tons of DELAYED INSERTs and this just happens to be the moment in time that they captured.  No way to know without more info.